Python np.char.add changes datatype / weird behavior
Can somebody explain the following behavior?
Input: a list of strings as a pandas series (it's a column of a bigger dataframe in fact).
Goal: Put a fixed single string "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" in front of all elements
Code:
s = pd.Series(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'])
s = np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s)
print(s)

Expected output:
['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODUCT'
 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY']

Actual output:
['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODU' <--- CT is missing here!
 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY']

It seems as if np.char.append somewhat silently changes the data type to something like <U28 or so. I get from various posts that there seems to be an involved problem with this simple functionality (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10062) but this behavior is definitely wrong... if it is complicated then at least fail with an error informing the user that there is some information missing... or am I completely overlooking something here?
What is the "correct" way of doing this simple "listified" operation (append a string to a string)?

Why not just print("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + s)?

@Dogbert I think I just copy pasted this solution from some stackexchange answer...
I tried your solution and I receive numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U18'), dtype('<U10')) -> None ... I mean I get the error I guess... but cmon, pandas... this is not user friendly :-D

This works for me: "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + pd.Series(["DAIPRODUCT", "DAISY"])

Ah I see... I want to do two different string manipulations... that's why I execute np.copy on my version of s ... that turns it into an np.ndarray...

why do you use numpy for this? Why not use pandas? Or keep data as normal list with strings and use list comprehension to create new values.

this also should work df['coumn_name'] = "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + df['coumn_name']. Eventually should works also df['coumn_name'] = df['coumn_name'].apply(lambda x: "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + x)

pandas Series with strings are object dtype. So the strings are native python, and can be joined with .'abc'+'def'.  np.char.add works with 'Un' numpy string dtype. If it chooses the wrong length for that dtype it can truncate.  I'd have to experiment to see how np.char.add interacts with the pandas series strings. It's not any faster.

Your Series (using the ipython 'repr' display:
In [320]: s
Out[320]: 
0    DAIPRODUCT
1         DAISY
dtype: object

Note that is object dtype.  That's normally how pandas stores strings.
The addition that's too short.  The result is numpy string dtype 'U26':
In [322]: np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s)
Out[322]: 
array(['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODU', 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY'],
      dtype='<U26')

np.char.add first converts the Series to a numpy array:
In [323]: np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s.to_numpy())
Out[323]: 
array(['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODU', 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY'],
      dtype='<U26')

If instead I tell it to convert the Series to a 'U' dtype, I get the full string lengths:
In [324]: np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s.to_numpy().astype('U'))
Out[324]: 
array(['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODUCT', 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY'],
      dtype='<U28')

Looking at how the conversions are done:
In [325]: s.to_numpy()
Out[325]: array(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'], dtype=object)

In [326]: s.to_numpy().astype('U')
Out[326]: array(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'], dtype='<U10')

np.char functions are wrappers for python string methods.  As noted the np.char package (and np.chararray) is legacy code, relatively old and not actively maintained.  I don't know why np.char.add got the result length 'U26' wrong.  Must be something in the conversion from object to numpy strings.  It works correctly if the argument(s) is a numpy 'U' string (as intended).
As noted by others, you can simply add the string to the Series.  Pandas has apparently defined an add operator for its Series.  In the case of strings it performs the desired join.
In [327]: "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + s
Out[327]: 
0    BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODUCT
1         BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY
dtype: object

This plus operator also works for the object dtype array:
In [333]: "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + s.to_numpy()
Out[333]: 
array(['BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAIPRODUCT', 'BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-DAISY'],
      dtype=object)

Math operators on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss.  It tries apply the operator individually to the elements of the array.  That depends on the elements implementing the operator.
In an array that's a mix of string and numbers, '*' does a replication on the string, and regular multiply on the number:
In [338]: np.array(['one', 1], object) * 3
Out[338]: array(['oneoneone', 3], dtype=object)

Same behavior for a Series with a mix of strings and numbers:
In [344]: pd.Series(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY',3]) *3
Out[344]: 
0    DAIPRODUCTDAIPRODUCTDAIPRODUCT
1                   DAISYDAISYDAISY
2                                 9
dtype: object


you could consider one of this three alternatives:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'])
s = "BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-" + s
print(s.values)

s = pd.Series(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'])
s = np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s.values.astype('<U18'))
print(s)

s = np.array(['DAIPRODUCT', 'DAISY'])
s = np.char.add("BI-AS-ATLASSIAN-P-", s)
print(s)

